# Enforcing Method Definition for a Class

Tags: python

I've written the following code to help enforce the definition of certain methods for a class:

```
def createClassTemplate(name, requiredMethods=[], inherits=object):
    def require(name):
        def errorRaiser(self, *args, **kwargs):
            raise RequireException("method '{}' must be defined.".format(name))
        setattr(wrapper, "__name__", name)
        return errorRaiser

    class Custom(inherits): pass

    setattr(Custom, "__name__", name)
    for methodName in requiredMethods:
        setattr(Custom, methodName, require(methodName))

    return Custom
```

Which is implemented like this:

```
Model = createClassTemplate("Model", ["foo", "bar", "baz"])

class MyClass(Model):
    pass
```

This way, when I'm missing a method, the calling class will generate a meaningful error indicating that I've failed to define a required method.

The problem is, the above code seems uncomfortably hacky and unpythonic. Am I going about this right way? Should I even be forcing class templates like this? And is there a better way to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a [metaclass](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation) instead.

The standard library comes with a ready-made metaclass for just this task, the [`ABCMeta` metaclass](http://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta):

```
import abc

class Model(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        pass

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def bar(self):
        pass

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def baz(self):
        pass

class MyClass(Model):
    pass
```

Demonstration:

```
>>> import abc
>>> class Model(object):
...     __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta
...     @abc.abstractmethod
...     def foo(self):
...         pass
...     @abc.abstractmethod
...     def bar(self):
...         pass
...     @abc.abstractmethod
...     def baz(self):
...         pass
... 
>>> class MyClass(Model):
...     pass
... 
>>> myclass = MyClass()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class MyClass with abstract methods bar, baz, foo
```

Once `MyClass` does provide implementations of the abstract methods, instantiation succeeds:

```
>>> class MyClass(Model):
...     def foo(self): pass
...     def bar(self): pass
...     def baz(self): pass
... 
>>> myclass = MyClass()
```

Comment: Clearly, I could spend some more time reading the docs -.- Thanks for the comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`ABCMeta`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta) metaclass:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class MyClass:
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        pass
```

Subclasses of `MyClass` must override `foo` to be allowed to be instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python 2.6+, there's the concept of an ABC - http://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are trying to reinvent the [Abstract Base Classes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html)

I think you want something like this:

```
import abc

class MyBaseClass:
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        pass

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def bar(self):
        pass

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def baz(self):
        pas
```